# xaml designer and color in VS2013 text based xaml editor

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

Here are two captures, can you see which node is selected in the XAML UI Editor ?

[image][image]

In the leftmost one the second tabitem is selected (look closely at the subtle change...)
In the rightmost one the frist tabitem is selected.

Which raises two questions :

- How is it possible that VS would chose such obviously bad default ?
- Which VS settings can be played with fix the color ?

Comment: This sounds like a rant rather than a proper question. And yes I can clearly see the highlight. Maybe your monitor / eyes are bad?

Comment: it could be a rant. but there is a genuine question about really bad ideas in product as well. it keeps making me speechless. why such obviously bad decisions. it says something. what is the explanation.

Comment: yes, it might be linked to the screen : on my macbook I can better see the faint  difference. not on monitors that comes with a standard high-end dell PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for why Microsoft would pick that color, I can't answer (I'm not Microsoft), but I can tell you how to change that color in your own environment.

1. Open Visual Studio
2. From the menu, click Tools > Options
3. In the dialog, choose Environment > Fonts and Colors in the left sidebar
4. In the "Display Items" box, choose "Highlighted Reference"
5. Change the color to what you want it to be.